# filter a pandas datafram based on the last rows of a key

Tags: python, pandas

i have a pandas dataframe with some thousand of rows. this dataframe is ordered by two columns: name (a hundred unique values), and date.
i want to create a fraction of this dataframe that took only the last like 50 rows of each unique value of name.
so if i have:

```
     Name    Date    
0    A       date1
1    A       date2
2    A       date3
3    A       date4
4    A       date5
5    A       date6
6    A       date7
7    A       date8
8    B       Date1
9    B       Date2
10   B       Date3
11   B       Date4
12   B       Date5
13   B       Date6
14   B       Date7
15   B       Date8
```

i want to have just:

```
     Name    Date    
0    A       date5
1    A       date6
2    A       date7
3    A       date8
4    B       Date5
5    B       Date6
6    B       Date7
7    B       Date8
```

each name does not have the same numbers of rows.

all my ideas for now had too many cycle. is something i can do to try if it work but i can't apply on too much rows.
any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df.groupby("Name").tail(4).reset_index(drop=True)

  Name   Date
0    A  date5
1    A  date6
2    A  date7
3    A  date8
4    B  Date5
5    B  Date6
6    B  Date7
7    B  Date8
```